# DataTables HTML Example are the same

Tags: datatable

can someone give me some help...
all example code on http://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/index.html are the same... I have hard time understanding this... please can someone really need help...

can anyone help me cause I'm new to these... but it gaves me always..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

all link sample on style I see are like these...

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I want example of `dataTables` because on site it's all the same... didn't it should have like `$('#example').dataTable(function(){ sampleOpt: sampleVal });`

Answer (score 0):

You need seriously read information about of Javascript, html, css and everything about of web page structure. The code that always you see refers to the overall structure of the datatable. If you want see the changes between examples simply select the tab css or html next to Javascript.

Sorry for my bad english.

regards.

Comment: no... as far I remember.... there is like this example of dataTables because on site it's all the same... didn't it should have like `$('#example').dataTable(function(){ sampleOpt: sampleVal });`